# sending email via Oulook with ipyvuetify

Tags: python, button, vuetify.js, mailto, ipywidgets

I am developing a little app where I would like to include a button that will open outlook email editor and presented the user with an empty content but a particular subject ready to be filled in by the user and sent back to a particular email.

Does anyone know how to do that?

What I was reading in different solutions does not work:

this for instance opens a url that fails

```
import ipyvuetify as v
v_btn = v.Btn(class_   = 'mx-2 light-blue darken-1', 
              href     = 'href="mailto:vinoth@email.com?subject=title&body=The message"',
                        children = ['send email?'])
v_btn
```

Other option might be to create a ipyvuetify template:

```
class sendemail(v.VuetifyTemplate):

    subject = Unicode('').tag(sync=True)
    label = Unicode('email').tag(sync=True)

    template = Unicode('''<v-btn
            color="primary"
            class="ma-1"
            @click="sendemail(subject)"
        >

            {{ theemail }}

        </v-btn>
    
        <script>
          export default {
            methods: {
              sendemail (subject) {
                var email = "whatever@company.org";
                document.location = "mailto:" + email +"?subject=" + subject + "&body=the body";
            },
            },
          }
        </script>''').tag(sync=True)
    
emailitBtn = clipboardBtn(subject='This is the subject of the email', label='send email')
emailitBtn
```

But this solution does not work neither.
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try

```
import ipyvuetify as v
v_btn = v.Btn(class_   = 'mx-2 light-blue darken-1', 
              href     = 'mailto:vinoth@email.com?subject=title&body=The message',
              target   = '_blank',
                        children = ['send email?'])
v_btn
```

I removed the 'href' in the href property and added target='_blank' to open it in a new Window and it seems to work.